# Calling a function show alert dialog from two different activities

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, applicationcontext

I came across a situation where tow of my activities should call same function. MainActivity and SMSActivity. I have written a HelperClass and created a function getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(). getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() shows alert dialog and does some work.

I am instantiating HelperClass from MainActivity and called helperclass.getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() by passing context is working fine.

But when I do the same from SMSActivity, application is crashing. I think this is because of wrong context but not sure.

When Initiating HelperClass(), I am calling HelperClass.getinstance(getApplicationContext()) from MainActivity and when doing it from SMSActivity, I am calling HelperClass.getinstalce(getApplicationContext()).

Below is code from MainActivity

```
    HelperClass helperclass = HelperClass.getInstalce(getApplicationContext());
    tagHandler.getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(rowData);
```

From SMSActivity

```
    HelperClass helperclass = HelperClass.getInstalce(getApplicationContext());
    helperclass.getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(rowData);
```

And part of HelperClass code is

```
    public class HelperClass {

Context context = null;
private static HelperClass HelperClass = null;

private HelperClass(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

public static synchronized HelperClass getInstalce(Context context) {
    if(helperclass == null) {
        helperclass = new TagHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    return helperclass;
}

public  void getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(final RowData rowData) {
    String selectedTitle = null;
String[] navTitles = = {"one", "tow", "Three"};

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context.getApplicationContext());
    alertDialog.setTitle("Select Category");
    alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(navTitles, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int title_position = which;
            String selectedTitle = navTitles[which];
            dialog.cancel();
            if (rowData.getInfoPath() != null) {
                //doing some work
            } else {
                //doing some work
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.create();
    ad.show();
}
```

}

Logcat show below error

```
        android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:570)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:306)
        at com.srids.tagit.TagHandler.getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(HelperClass.java:75)
        at com.srids.tagit.SMSActivity$2.onClick(SMSActivity.java:140)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

where HelperClass.java:75 is ad.show(). I suspect issue could be with the context passed but not sure how to resolve the issue.

MainActivity code part. It is huge so putting onCreate() code of it:

```
    Below is the code

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.FragmentDrawerListener, shareDataInterface {

private Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment;
HelperClass helperclass = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("tagIt");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("make search easy..");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    utils= new Utils();
    prefs = MyPrefs.getInstance(this);
    if(prefs.getBool(MyGlobals.PASSWORD_PROTECT) == true) {
        if(loggedin == 0) {
            loggedin = 1;
            utils.showDialog(MainActivity.this, MyGlobals.DIALOG_PIN_INPUT);
        }
    }

    // populate navigation drawer
    navigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    navigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    navigationDrawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // establish data base connection and first read tags list for NAV drawer
    db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    navTitles =navigationDrawerFragment.titles;

    // create tag handler
    helperclass = HelperClass.getInstalce(getApplicationContext());
```

}

}

Comment: Where do you call helperclass.getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(rowData); ? In what part of the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done isn't the proper way to handle such senarios **Update your code**

```
  public class HelperClass {

    public static void getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(final Context context,final RowData rowData) {
        String selectedTitle = null;
    String[] navTitles = = {"one", "tow", "Three"};

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Select Category");
        alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(navTitles, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int title_position = which;
                String selectedTitle = navTitles[which];
                dialog.cancel();
                if (rowData.getInfoPath() != null) {
                    //doing some work
                } else {
                    //doing some work
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.create();
        ad.show();
    }

    }
```

**Usage**

```
HelperClass.getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(MainActivty.this,rowData);
```

Replace MainActivity code with below

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.FragmentDrawerListener, shareDataInterface {

private Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("tagIt");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("make search easy..");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    utils= new Utils();
    prefs = MyPrefs.getInstance(this);
    if(prefs.getBool(MyGlobals.PASSWORD_PROTECT) == true) {
        if(loggedin == 0) {
            loggedin = 1;
            utils.showDialog(MainActivity.this, MyGlobals.DIALOG_PIN_INPUT);
        }
    }

    // populate navigation drawer
    navigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    navigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    navigationDrawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // establish data base connection and first read tags list for NAV drawer
    db = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    navTitles =navigationDrawerFragment.titles;

 //Get your rowdata before calling the method

  HelperClass.getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(MainActivty.this,rowData);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried and I am getting and error saying MainActivity.this is not an enclosing class.

Comment: is your MainActivty extends Activity ?

Comment: It  extends ActionBarActivity. In fact Both activities.

Comment: first of all ActionBarActivity is deprecated.post your MainActivity class

Comment: Thank you. It helped in resolving the issue

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use application Context to show your dialog, instead of activity. There is not view for dialog to attach to the application Context. If you want to show two dialogs at the MainActivity and SMSActivity, you need to update the context value in the class HelperClass.

Maybe you can change your code like that:

MainActivity

```
HelperClass helperclass = HelperClass.getInstalce();
helperclass .getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(MainActivity.this, rowData);
```

SMSActivity

```
HelperClass helperclass = HelperClass.getInstalce();
helperclass .getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(SMSActivity.this, rowData);
```

HelperClass

```
public class HelperClass {

private static HelperClass helperclass = null;

private HelperClass() {

}

public static synchronized HelperClass getInstalce() {
    if (helperclass == null) {
        helperclass = new HelperClass();
    }
    return helperclass;
}

public void getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(Context context, final RowData rowData) {
    String selectedTitle = null;
    String[] navTitles = {"one", "tow", "Three"};

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Select Category");
    alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(navTitles, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int title_position = which;
            String selectedTitle = navTitles[which];
            dialog.cancel();
            if (rowData.getInfoPath() != null) {
                //doing some work
            } else {
                //doing some work
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.create();
    ad.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the anoop's answer please do this for better perfomance
If you are using application class put the below code in application class,

```
HelperClass mHelperClass;
public final HelperClass getHelperClass() {
    if(mHelperClass == null) {
        mHelperClass = new HelperClass();
    }
    return mHelperClass;
}
```

and use the getHelperClass() method wherever you want.

Hope this may help you..

Comment: Thank you. But What I am looking here is a function implemented to show alertdialog requires context. If the function to be used from two different activities, what is the context should be passed so that when using from different activities, I should be able to show alertdialog. I feel logcar errors more related to those as error is showing at ad.show().

Comment: okay.. Instead of this reference use MainActivity.this.getBaseContext()